# Привести в порядок название действий с вопросом

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, переоткрытие-вопросов

Под закрытым вопросом, например под [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569044/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) видим такую картину:

> [image: reopen]

Если не брать в расчет `тревога`, то верхняя строка содержит два глагола и одно существительное. Считаю, что надо привести всё к одному виду.

Если посмотреть на активный вопрос, то картина следующая:

> [image: active]

Т.е. везде глаголы.

Comment: А тревога заменить на что? Тревожить? Тревогнуть? Имхо чрезмерный ненужный перфекционизм

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вообще `сигнализировать` (или `отметить тревогой`). Но, во-первых, я её выделил особо в вопросе, во-вторых, мне кажется, этот пункт уже имеет устоявшееся название. Хотя, ничто не вечно под луной :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в первую очередь вопрос был задан про `закрыть` и `переоткрытие`, т.к. действия связанные, а потом уже решил обобщить на остальные ссылки. Возможно этого не стоило делать, т.к. по более широкому вопросу сложнее придти к консенсусу.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Тревогните, чтобы начать!

Comment: @NickVolynkin `потревожить` модератора

Comment: @alexolut: :) разбудить модератора

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Изменить `переоткрытие` на `переоткрыть`.

Comment: В оригинале reopen, это глагол.

Comment: @NickVolynkin с `flag` несколько сложнее

Comment: Тоже глагол, to flag. Но на русский не так просто переводится.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я понимаю, но ведь есть и существительное `flag`. iOS еще такое предложил - ⛳️ :) не знаю, отобразится ли у других.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, лучше будет звучать `открыть снова`. (Но будет длиннее, да.)

Comment: Другая проблема - это два слова при отсутствии специальных разделителей с другими ссылками. Хотя при наведении мыши подсветка всё же есть.

Answer (score 0):

Следует оставить как есть. Работает - не трожь!

Answer (score -5):

Заменить `править` на `правка`

Comment: А `поделиться` на `поделение`? :)

Comment: Или наоборот поменять чтобы было прилагательное и наречие для разнообразия

Comment: @alexolut `поделиться` можно заменить на `ссылка сюда`